# Redux-updating one element in array based on return from back end

Tags: redux, react-redux

I have a React-Redux app, and am building update functionality. I have a list of plots in state, and update one of them. A successful update API call gets the updated plot as a response. How do I replace the old plot with the updated plot in state?

Right now, this is my reducer. I'm seeing the updated plot getting logged, but it is not replaced in state unless I reload. I can always trigger a reload of the whole plot list from the back end on success, but would like to avoid the unnecessary call.

```
case UPDATED_PLOT:
            action.payload.id = action.payload._id;
            console.log('updated plot received by reducer: ', action.payload);
            return {
                ...state,
                filteredPlots: state.filteredPlots.map(
                    plot => (plot.id == action.payload.id ? action.payload : plot)
                )
            };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reducer code looks fine to me. How did you conclude that the redux state did note get updated? Have you tried installing [redux-dev-tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en) to make sure that the state has not been updated?

If you're sure that the state has been updated, it might be worth checking whether your components have re-rendered. You can instrument componentWillUpdate() in a particular component. Also, its worth checking the docs for [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options), especially the "pure" option.

Comment: I am sure that the React state did not get updated, because I'm looking at it with React Dev Tools. Redux Dev Tools doesn't work for me (can't figure it out.)

Comment: where does react dev tools show you the redux state? The point I'm trying to make is that there might be a problem in the way that your redux state is passed into react.

Comment: React-dev shows me those parts of redux state which are passed into any particular React component. I can see the filtered plots in there, since the component maps this part of state into its props. They do not change.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
case UPDATED_PLOT:
    action.payload.id = action.payload._id;
    const new_filtered_plots = state.filteredPlots.map(plot => {
       return plot.id == action.payload.id ? action.payload : plot
    });
    return Object.assign({}, state, {filteredPlots: new_filtered_plots});
```

Comment: Tried it, it doesn't work. How is this better than using ...spread?